# How to check if wp_mail has sent a email

Tags: php, wordpress, email

I want to check whether an email is sent out using

```
wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers, $attachments );
```

But according to the wordpress documentation.

The return type tells  whether the email contents were sent successfully.

Also it says, A true return value does not automatically mean that the user received the email successfully. It just only means that the method used was able to process the request without any errors

So my question is how to trace whether has successfully reached the recipients inbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try sending `Disposition-Notification-To` email header.

```
$headers = "Disposition-Notification-To: yourEmailID\n";
```

Comment: so wp_mail will return 1 only if the mail is sent out then? is that correct

Comment: yes. by adding this header a message delivery notification will be made to the specified email address

Comment: *Years later - this works well, It asks the user to notify that the email has been read - Though I can not seem to get it to work on androids gmail app.